# R/data.table: separate columns and count occurrences

Tags: r, data.table

I have a large `data.table` (just showing five lines here).

```
 taxpath                                                                                                                  N
                  Bacteroidetes; Flavobacteriia; Flavobacteriales; Flavobacteriaceae; Formosa; Formosa sp. Hel3_A1_48;   57
 Bacteroidetes; Flavobacteriia; Flavobacteriales; Cryomorphaceae; NA; Cryomorphaceae bacterium BACL29 MAG-121220-bin8;   54
                Proteobacteria; Alphaproteobacteria; Pelagibacterales; Pelagibacteraceae; Candidatus Pelagibacter; NA;   53
                                                    Proteobacteria; Alphaproteobacteria; Pelagibacterales; NA; NA; NA;   41
                                                      Planctomycetes; NA; NA; NA; NA; Planctomycetes bacterium TMED84;   41
```

The first column is `taxpath` (phylum, class, order, family, genus, species from left to right), the second column is `N`, how often each taxpath occurs.

What I would like to do is to split each taxpath by the semicolon and use the first entry.

And I want to calculate how often each phylum rank (the first rank, so Bacteriodetes, Proteobacteria or Planctomycetes) occurs. However, this number should be multiplied with the value in the column N.

So, what I expect is more or less something like this.

```
phylum           Nnew
Bacteriodetes    111
Proteobacteria   94
Planctomycetes   41
```

Can you help me how to do the split within the column and the - I suppose - group-by multiplied with the column N?

(PS: later, I want to do that as well with the other elements in the column taxpath as well, but I thought it is easier to distribute this into seperate tables)

Comment: Second part of the question is not clear.  Can you show the expected

Comment: For instance, Proteobacteria occurs in two lines (line #3 and line#8). line #3 has the value 53 and line #8 41. The output I would expect would be column _phylum_ has the entry proteobacteria and the column _Nnew_ has the value 94 (53+41). Is it clear what I mean?

Comment: Can you please check the updated code

Comment: Based on the exampl, I get `Bacteriodetes` as 326

Comment: Thank you, I have shortened the input data to 5 lines instead of 10.

Comment: No problem, my output is  based on the 10 lines you earlier showed

Comment: Wonderful, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `separate` to split the 'taxpath' into the specified columns based on the delimiter `;`, grouped by 'phylum', get the `sum` of 'N'

```
library(tidyverse) 
newcols <-c("phylum", "class", "order", "family", "genus", "species")
df1 %>% 
   mutate(taxpath = sub(";$", "", taxpath)) %>%
   separate(taxpath, into = newcols, sep= ";\\s*") %>% 
   group_by(phylum) %>%
   summarise(Nnew = sum(N))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#   phylum          Nnew
#   <chr>          <int>
# 1 Bacteroidetes    326
# 2 Planctomycetes    41
# 3 Proteobacteria    94
```

Answer (score 2):

This tagged [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) so here's a simple data.table solution.

```
library(data.table)
DT[, .(Nnew = sum(N)), by = sub(";.*", "", taxpath)]
#               sub Nnew
# 1:  Bacteroidetes  111
# 2: Proteobacteria   94
# 3: Planctomycetes   41
```

We basically summed `N` while extracting the first part of `taxpath` on the fly in the `by` statement

---

Data

```
DT <- fread("taxpath\t                                                                                                                  N
            Bacteroidetes; Flavobacteriia; Flavobacteriales; Flavobacteriaceae; Formosa; Formosa sp. Hel3_A1_48;\t   57
            Bacteroidetes; Flavobacteriia; Flavobacteriales; Cryomorphaceae; NA; Cryomorphaceae bacterium BACL29 MAG-121220-bin8;\t   54
            Proteobacteria; Alphaproteobacteria; Pelagibacterales; Pelagibacteraceae; Candidatus Pelagibacter; NA;\t   53
            Proteobacteria; Alphaproteobacteria; Pelagibacterales; NA; NA; NA;\t   41
            Planctomycetes; NA; NA; NA; NA; Planctomycetes bacterium TMED84;\t   41")
```